# how to set initial value(not manual input) of newton raphson method in python

Tags: python, newtons-method

I would like find the roots of equation x2-x-6 using Newton Raphson method.

how to take initial value x0 by coding.

```
tried with for loop
for k in list(range(i-1, i)):
    print("x0", k)
    new_fun(x0)
    x0 = k + 0.5
    print(x0)
```

Where i and i-1 are boundaries

Comment: How exactly do you want to set this value? You could just replace the input line with `x0 = 0`, for instance. Did you instead want a randomly selected initial value?

Comment: Yes, but i want to loop through i-1, i with increasing numbers 0.5 or 1. I tried for loop but it is giving for first value then it is not looping through next values

Comment: What exactly is `i` in this context? Note that `list(range(i-1,i))` is a list that contains only the value `i-1`, but I suspect that this is not what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

A for loop that seems much more reasonable to me is the following.

```
m_min = 0  # min value
x_max = 10 # max value
dx = 0.5  # increment

for x0 in range(x_min,x_max+dx,dx):
    print("x0:",x0)
    newton(x0)
```